# Map image not getting displayed in Saved links IDX Broker Equity theme

Tags: wordpress, idx

I am using IDXBroker account and AgentEvolution Equity theme for http://www.accessrealtytampa.com . There is no map displayed on any of the saved links page. I tried to clear the cache and check the wrapper settings and script is also present in the  section.

Here is the saved link

Please let me know if I am missing out something.

Answer (score 0):

Often the issue is CSS taking down the container size to zero, but without the saved link the link I can't be sure.

I see a link to the site, but which saved link is not showing a map?

Have you mailed into developer support?

Comment: Actually, I checked your map search page: http://homes.accessrealtytampa.com/idx/map/mapsearch and it's all maps just showing gray not just saved links. Looks like your scripting is conflicting with the map script. You can see the map works when your scripts are removed. This is done in IDX with ?bare. 

Example: http://homes.accessrealtytampa.com/idx/map/mapsearch?
bare
You just need to remove the conflicting script from your pages.